# What mysql command can show me the tables in a database and how many rows there are?

Tags: command-line, mysql, database

is there a mysql command that will show me the tables and how many rows they have in them?

Comment: obviously this was a valid question with 2500 views! dont see why it has to be closed just because a few thought it didn't pertain to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in MySQL 5 you can query the virtual table `information_schema` which contains metadata about the tables within your MySQL database.

To find out the number of rows for every table across every database:

```
$ mysql -u root -p \
    -e "select table_schema,table_name,table_rows from information_schema.tables;"
+---------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| table_schema        | table_name                            | table_rows |
+---------------------+---------------------------------------+------------+
| information_schema  | CHARACTER_SETS                        |       NULL | 
| information_schema  | COLLATIONS                            |       NULL | 
| information_schema  | COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY |       NULL | 
...
...
| arrdb01             | active_part                           |         24 | 
| arrdb01             | audit_record                          |         19 | 
| arrdb01             | code                                  |          8 | 
| arrdb01             | part_obj                              |          0 | 
| arrdb02             | active_part                           |         24 | 
| arrdb02             | audit_record                          |         14 | 
| arrdb02             | code                                  |          9 | 
| arrdb02             | part_obj                              |          1 | 
| cacti               | cdef                                  |          8 | 
| cacti               | cdef_items                            |         22 | 
| cacti               | colors                                |        215 | 
...
...
```

The above command is selecting 3 columns from the information_schema table:

- table_schema  (database name)
- table_name
- table_rows

To see all the fields that it contains you can use the describe command:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e "describe information_schema.tables"
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| TABLE_CATALOG   | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| TABLE_SCHEMA    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       | 
| TABLE_NAME      | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       | 
| TABLE_TYPE      | varchar(64)  | NO   |     |         |       | 
| ENGINE          | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| VERSION         | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| ROW_FORMAT      | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| TABLE_ROWS      | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AVG_ROW_LENGTH  | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| DATA_LENGTH     | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| MAX_DATA_LENGTH | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| INDEX_LENGTH    | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| DATA_FREE       | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| AUTO_INCREMENT  | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| CREATE_TIME     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| UPDATE_TIME     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| CHECK_TIME      | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| TABLE_COLLATION | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| CHECKSUM        | bigint(21)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| CREATE_OPTIONS  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| TABLE_COMMENT   | varchar(80)  | NO   |     |         |       | 
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

#### References

- [Overview of MySQL information_schema Database With Practical Examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-mysql-information_schema-database-with-practical-examples/)
- [Chapter 20. INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-schema.html)
- [MySQL command to show list of databases on server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-command-to-show-list-of-databases-on-server/)

Answer (score 3):

```
connect name_of_database;
show tables;
select count(*) from name_of_database.name_of_table;
```

To get a complete list of qualified table names:

```
select concat(table_schema, '.', table_name) from information_schema.tables;
```

Comment: thanks! how do you add a wildcard to name_of_tables. I just want to see specific tables that match a specific pattern. select count(*) from name_of_database.*_foo; ???

Comment: @duckx One way is to list the table names and use `sed` to filter the table names you want, then reinject the result into a mysql command. There's probably a way to do it in pure MySQL, but I don't know how. You should ask SQL questions on [so].

Answer (score 2):

After selecting the database try:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '%'
```

Reference:

http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/administration/mysql_tables_statistics_size_engine_no_of_rows_etc.php